# Webcam not detected after installing ubuntu 18.04 on macBook 2,1

Tags: 18.04, webcam, macbook

I have installed ubuntu 18.04 LTS on my macBook 2,1. After installing, cheese is working perfectly but whenever i am trying to connect through zoom or something like video calling softwares it show "something went wrong, no webcam and microphone detected".

Comment: Hey hafizaatifkamal! What do you mean by "2,1"? Is it the model number?

Comment: Yes, it is the model number.